# Is it allowed to use the phrase “karma”

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

Is one allowed to use the word karma to describe something that happened? Karma being defined here as something happening to you specifically because you just did that same something to someone else (give or take). For instance, your friend trips and you laugh at him, and then a minute later you trip as well. Are you allowed to call this karma, or it that Avodah Zara since it comes from a different religion? Do we view karma as middah knegged middah simply?

Comment: Just a thought ...the Shulchan Aruch forbids using a house of Avodah Zarah as a landmark when giving directions (e g. Walk past the house of Avodah Zarah , then turn left)...how much more so (seemingly) to refer to a thoroughly Jewish concept with their nomenclature

Comment: @יהושעק very interesting thanks for sharing